# Is there a way to access the DOM object from a Mobile project

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4

StageWebView is a way to display HTML content on devices where the HTMLLoader class is not supported. Having that into account, is the htmlLoader the only possible way that of accessing DOM objects from ActionScript. Does anyone know of another way that would work on a mobile project?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your end goal is?  Generally, when I need JS information, I use ExternalInterface, but that's rare and I don't know how it will work in a mobile AIR app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the html content, then this may be possible via loadURL and the "javascript:" protocol:

http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2010/10/making-the-most-of-stagewebview/